# POST a variable to a website accepting JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, httpwebrequest

As the title is referring, there is a website that requires a key in order to authenticate. The key is processed by the website and it spits it out.
I built a program that gets the key, filters it out from the HTML response and prints it.

All I need to know is how do I post this key that is a JavaScript variable "key=" onto the website "https://www.website.com/serve/credit"
This is the JavaScript on the website:

```
 key = jQuery('#my_key').val();
    jQuery.post('/serve/credit', "key=" + key);
```

That was the JavaScript off of the website;

```
Console.WriteLine(resultString); //resultString is the key that I filter

                byte[] postByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(resultString);

                HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.website.com/serve/credit");
                request2.KeepAlive = true;
                request2.Timeout = 15000;
                //request2.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36";
                //request2.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                //request2.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-us,en;q=0.5");
                request2.Method = "POST";
                request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request2.ContentLength = postByte.Length;
                Stream postStream = request2.GetRequestStream();
                postStream.Write(postByte, 0, postByte.Length);
                postStream.Close();

                HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string result2 = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

Comment: Post the variable using Ajax?You have the data, the URL and the method.

Comment: I don't know how to, that is why this question is here

Comment: Also, how is the website "accepting" javascript? slightly confused about that

Comment: Not sure, I do not own the website. I am trying to post a variable, stringResult which is equal to "key=1092491498" and is taken as a variable on the website.

Comment: Try something like this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/